# Add item to RecyclerView when a Button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to add items to RecyclerView when I click the "Add" button

This currently works but only once , meaning if I click the Add button the first time, the item is added and visible, but after that, nothing is added.

Here is my code for RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.myViewHolder> {

    List<Integer> listItem;

    public Adapter(List<Integer> passedListItem){
        this.listItem = passedListItem;
    }

    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, parent, false);

        myViewHolder holder = new myViewHolder(itemView);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int itemNumber = position+1;
        holder.itemTextView.setText("Item Number " + itemNumber + ": " + listItem.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItem.size();
    }

    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView itemTextView;

        public myViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            itemTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Integer> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    EditText itemEditText;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Adapter rvAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_itemsRecyclerView);
        itemEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_editText);

        //Setting the layout and Adapter for RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        rvAdapter = new Adapter(itemList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
    }

    //Click listener for "Add" Button
    public void onAddButtonClicked(View view) {

        try {
            int IntegerFormat = Integer.valueOf(itemEditText.getText().toString());
            itemList.add(IntegerFormat);
            rvAdapter.notifyItemInserted(itemList.size() - 1);
            itemEditText.setText("");
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The field is empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

When i click the Add button, the first item is added and is visible, but when I click the Add button second time, nothing happens.

---

#### Solved

EDIT: Apparently, my Recycler view layout had its width and height set to match_parent instead of wrap_content, so the second item was getting added after clicking the button but it was added way way below. And I was stupid enough to not even try to scroll down. Everything was just working fine but I was ignorent.

Comment: please try  rvAdapter.notifydatachanged(); instead of  rvAdapter.notifyItemInserted(itemList.size() - 1);

Comment: Tired but didn't work

Comment: can you please add your xml file here?both xml files for layout activity and adapter items

Comment: @Lokesh Desai thanks for asking for the XML file. You made me realise my mistake. I've edited my question to include what happened.

Comment: enjoy buddy..happy that your problem is solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just checked your code and it is working fine. The mistake is in the **recyclerview_layout.xml** file which you havent posted. What you have is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_itemTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please change this to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_itemTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your first list item is filling the entire recycler view because your linear layout  has **android:layout_height="match_parent"** instead of **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** so the first item is hiding the other items but they are there in the adapter. You can confirm this by logging in logcat.

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark as answer if that helped you so that people who have the same problem in future may quickly find the solution.