# Adding Items in Recycler View

Tags: java, android

Since I am new in Android development, I was working on a project for learning purposes but I am stuck. I saw this on mmt (Make my trip Application) and I want to build something like it: getting the add button below the Adapter item, or maybe in to the Footer.

If you haven't seen the application, kindly download, make my trip and in book flight section select "multicity".

If it is aduplicate, kindly don't mark it as duplicate, just refer me to the link.

Although its been 3 days, I am done searching and tried my ideas, but was not able to achieve this thing!

[image: Click here to see Image , what i want]

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46999770/4399414

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you trying to add a button as a footer for your RecyclerView?

Comment: please try to explain what you want i m not getting the question

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and if you need more help don't hesitate to ask.

Inside your button `onClick` event, access the `recyclerview` attached `adapter` and data list that you using to populate the `recyclerview`.
Inside your `adapter` create new method to set new data list.

```
public void setItems(List<Item> itemsList) {
        this.mItemList = itemsList;
}
```

In your `activity` or `fragment` in button `onClick` event, create your new Dataset, and add it to the existing data list that you using to populate the `recyclerview`.
Then In you `activity` or `fragment` in button `onClick` event, add below code.

```
mAdapter.setItems(mItemList);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```